# What is the scala notation written as _:type?

Tags: scala, function-literal

I'm following the scala tutorial.

In function literal, it has a following notation:

```
(_ : *type*) => println("pressed")
```

For example,

```
(_ : Int) => println("pressed")
```

In this notation, I couldn't understand what **(_ : *type*)** means.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's an anonymous function with an ignored parameter.
In Scala the convention is to use an underscore whenever you're not using a parameter.

You could rewrite the exact same thing like this:

```
(unused: Int) => println("pressed")
```

As to why someone would want to do this; oftentimes you need to appease Scala's type inference. So if you only wrote

```
_ => println("pressed")
```

then Scala wouldn't be able to infer the type of the input parameter. Typing it as

```
(_: Int) => println("pressed")
```

assures that the type inferred by the compiler is `Int => Unit`.